# Qt how to insert html into an editable QWebView at the cursor position?

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I'm trying to use `QWebView` to implement a blog post editor. And I have some sample html snippets to insert into the editor by triggering menu actions. However, it's not convenient as `QTextEdit` to insert html. As for why I don't use `QTextEdit`, see my test code following:

```
QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit;
edit->insertHtml(tr("<div class=\"gci-hello\">Hello</div>"));
qDebug() << edit->toHtml(); // --> the div tag disappeared
```

So, if I use QWebView, the div tag will be reserved. But I can't find out how to insert my snippet at the cursor postion on the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `execCommand` with `InsertHTML` :

```
QString html = "<div>Some text</div>";
QString js = QString("document.execCommand('InsertHTML',false,'%1');").arg(html);
webview->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

And if there are single quote characters in the HTML snippet, make sure you quote them with a backslash, since the snippet is injected through a JS string.